# Why can we make a pointer variable of a class which is forward declared and not make an object of that class?

Tags: objective-c, forward-declaration

eg:

```
@class X 
interface Y: NSObject
{ 
X *x;  //correct
X x;    //incorrect
}
```

Why so? How does it know where to point to in the pointer's case?
Thanks

Comment: Objective-C doesn't support `X x` even if `X` isn't a forward declaration. All references to objects in Objective-C must be pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The root of the confusion appears to be your question:

> How does it know where to point to in the pointer's case?

Ask yourself when you declare:

```
int x;
```

how does it know what value to give `x`? You have declared a *variable* with a name, `x`, of some type, `int`, and a variable is a container for a *value*. What is the value?

Depending on the language and kind (global, local, instance, etc.) of the variable the two common answers are (a) undefined - something arbitrary you cannot depend upon and (b) the zero of the type - `0` for the above `int`. The answer is **not** (c) some specific value, say `42`.

Now let's look at the declaration in your question:

```
X *x;
```

You have a variable with a name, `x`, of some type, `X *`, and the question is what value will be placed in this variable. So does modern (ARC) Objective-C pick (a) or (b) for `X *` where `X` is a class type? It picks (b) and the zero for `X *` is `nil`. As above the answer is **not** (c), a pointer to some specific instance of `X`.

In other words the answer to your question

> How does it know where to point to in the pointer's case?

Is it doesn't point anywhere, the zero pointer value, aka `nil`, is used.

Moving to the second issue arising from your question, you also declare:

```
X x;
```

where `X` is a class type, and note that it is incorrect. In Objective-C all instances of classes must be referenced via a pointer, there are no "value classes" - if you need those you use structures (`struct`).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is simply a pointer. It has fixed size no matter what it points to. So it's *type* serves merely as an extra information (as kind of a cast). If you mess things up this will show up at run-time.

On the other hand: compiler needs exact class *footprint* to create an instance of that class.

EDIT: as rmaddy pointed out in comments, your `X x;` line of code is not supported in Objective-C in any case: you will always deal with pointers (of some level) to instances/objects.